# Select Distinct from one column when another column differs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp1 
(
    Category_One varchar(10),
    Category_Two varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO #Temp1 (Category_One, Category_Two)
VALUES ('a', 'c'), 
       ('b', 'c'),
       ('a', 'd'),
       ('b', 'd'),
       ('a', 'e'),
       ('a', 'f'),
       ('b', 'g')
```

| Category_One | Category_Two |
| --- | --- |
| a | c |
| b | c |
| a | d |
| b | d |
| a | e |
| a | f |
| b | g |

How do I return a table like this, that returns a distinct list from `CategoryTwo`, but also returns an extra column that tells me whether or not the final category is made up of two separate `CategoryOne`'s?

| Category_Final | Description |
| --- | --- |
| c | Category a and b |
| d | Category a and b |
| e | Category a |
| f | Category a |
| g | Category b |

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running? `STRING_AGG` would be the way to go probably if you have access to it. Does the description _have_ to be in that exact format or would it be OK to have something like "Category a, b"? How should the string be formatted if you have three or more subcategories?

Comment: You can use `PIVOT` also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running a version of SQL Server that supports `string_agg`  (2017+) and you're fine with the word "and" being repeated multiple times if you have three or more `category_one` values, this should work:

```
select 
    Category_two, 
    Description = 
       'Category ' + 
       string_agg(category_one, ' and ') within group (order by category_one)
from #Temp1
group by Category_two
```

Just note if you have three or more `category_one` values, the word "and" is going to be repeated between each item.

Here are the docs on the function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2016

Comment: Great solution.  I also didn't know string_agg() was a function, thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help